# The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information

Tags: 2013, workflow, development, publishing-site

I am working on an EnterpriseWiki Site collection, and i define the following workflow which fires when modifying the wiki page,, where its first step is to check if the Wiki page name & title is different ,, then set the Title= Name. the workflow is as follow:-

[image]

now sometimes i face a problem with the workflow and it show the following errors:-

[image]

but if i re-edit the wiki page again with the same info the workflow will work well,, so i think this happens for a reason not related to the data (as the error indicates) , because as i mentioned if i re-edit the wiki page with the same data the workflow will work well...

can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it works now and then, we can rule out permissions issue.
Try adding a wait (pause) step before you update the list item in the WF.